# parse check whether user exists and use user's name in a label

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am using parse to verify whether a user exists (for example: an other user searches for "userX" and if "userX" exists he will send him a message).

On Parse website they recommend the following code:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("gender", equalTo:"female")
var girls = query.findObjects()
```

Referred to : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-querying/iOS

I am using that code transformed it to:

```
 var query = PFUser.query()
 query.whereKey("username", equalTo:typeName.text)
 var usernameP = query.findObjects()
```

But then when i look at `println(usernameP)` I get an array.
 But i want to transform the username ("treert" in this case) into a String that I can put in a label.

Does anybody know how to do that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, `usernameP` contains an array. The clue is in the function you've called `findObjects` (plural). Your query will return **all objects** where `username = typeName.text`.

If you only want the first object found, then you will need to call `query.getFirstObject()`.

An alternative is to continue to call `findObjects()`, but then process the array of results, extracting the object you think is the correct one (assuming the array has more than 0 objects in it), and set the name based on that object.